# Search Duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to check if there are duplicates in my table `ParticipantsDebtor`, duplication is compared to Name, `ParticipantsCode` and `DateOfBirth` the `Name` and `ParticipantsCode` field  is in the `ParticipantsDebtor` table and `DateOfBirth` is in `ParticipantDebtorDetail` table, my request turns into the void I do not know if this is correct but very long or it is false

Table `ParticipantsDebtor` has:

- DebtorId
- Name
- ParticipantsCode

Table `ParticipantDebtorDetail` has:

- DebtorId
- DateOfBirth

Query:

```
SELECT a.ParticipantCode,
       a.Name,
       COUNT(a.DebtorId) AS DuplicateNumber,
       b.DateOfBirth
FROM ParticipantDebtors a WITH (NOLOCK),
     crem.ParticipantDebtorDetail b WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE a.DebtorId <> b.DebtorId
GROUP BY a.ParticipantCode,
         a.Name,
         b.DateOfBirth
HAVING COUNT(a.DebtorId) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not correct.  You need `join` keys . . . Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT d.ParticipantCode, d.Name, dd.DateOfBirth, COUNT(*) as NumDups
FROM ParticipantDebtors d with(nolock) JOIN
     crem.ParticipantDebtorDetail dd  with(nolock)
     ON d.DebtorId = dd.DebtorId
GROUP BY d.ParticipantCode, d.Name, dd.DateOfBirth
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

If a single debtor can appear in either table more than once, then you can replace the `HAVING` condition and calculation of `NumDups` with:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.DebtorID) > 1
```

Comment: I get wrong result, NumDups is always between 2 and 3 this is wrong in my table why ?

Comment: @khadi8 . . . I can't answer that without more information.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle with sample data that shows the problem.